# Can not access OrderHasComment public methods from prePersist event listener

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to access `setUser()` method from `prePersist()` on listener but I get this error:

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method
>   PL\OrderBundle\Entity\Order::setUser() in
>   /var/www/html/apps/portal_de_logistica/src/PL/OrderBundle/Listener/OrderHasCommentListener.php
>   line 23

This is the method:

```
/**
 *
 * @param LifecycleEventArgs $args 
 */
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
    $entity->setUser($user);
}
```

Why it access `Order` instead of `OrderHasComment`? How I fix that? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doctrine.event_listener will be listening for all entities in your application, if you want only to act on "OrderHasComment" entity just check the instance of class.

```
    if ($entity instanceof OrderHasComment) {
        $entity->setUser($user);
    }
```